# How can you add multiple galleries to the poptrox lightbox gallery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a lightbox poptrox gallery installed on my website. Each thumbnail however opens the full image of that thumbnail and when you click next/previous it moves to a picture of the next thumbnail.

Is it possible to make each thumbnail contain a gallery of it's own and when you click on it the full screen image is part of the gallery. That way when you clock next/previous it scrolls through its unique collection of images.

I used this to set it up https://github.com/n33/jquery.poptrox.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: can you add a example of what you have?  we like to help but we like to know what you have done

Answer (score 1):

According to the site you set up your gallery like

```
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="path/to/image1.jpg"><img src="path/to/image1_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image2.jpg"><img src="path/to/image2_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image3.jpg"><img src="path/to/image3_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image4.jpg"><img src="path/to/image4_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image5.jpg"><img src="path/to/image5_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image6.jpg"><img src="path/to/image6_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

and you have a jQuery call like

```
var foo = $('#gallery');
foo.poptrox();
```

so you just need to add another gallery like

```
<div id="gallery1">
    <a href="path/to/image1.jpg"><img src="path/to/image1_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image2.jpg"><img src="path/to/image2_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image3.jpg"><img src="path/to/image3_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image4.jpg"><img src="path/to/image4_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image5.jpg"><img src="path/to/image5_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image6.jpg"><img src="path/to/image6_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
</div>

<div id="gallery2">
    <a href="path/to/image1.jpg"><img src="path/to/image1_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image2.jpg"><img src="path/to/image2_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image3.jpg"><img src="path/to/image3_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image4.jpg"><img src="path/to/image4_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image5.jpg"><img src="path/to/image5_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="path/to/image6.jpg"><img src="path/to/image6_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

and add another jQuery

```
var foo = $('#gallery1');
foo1.poptrox();
var foo2 = $('#gallery2');
foo1.poptrox();
```

I hope that this helps, also if you post you have tried I can see how to better help